How to ensure the downtime is functioning in ResourcePool Element in Anylogic
I have the following downtime block

That I have included in the resourcePool block ATC,

And I am triggering the downtime using
if(unit.Processed==45){
downtime.startTask(unit);
unit.Processed=0;}

I have ensure the downtime start and stop time is working using pauseSimulation();
But in between the start time and end time, it seems like the ATC is still working and the flow chart is still moving. During downtime, the ATC capacity should be reduced to 0 right, so that It does not work.
Update: As a fix, I am currently using the following method and it works for the time being. But still I need to know if this is a required step, or there was a default feature in the downtime block that I missed that should have dont it automatically.


You do not activate downtimes actively. The blocks do that themselves, this is how they are designed to be used.
(Yes, there is a public startTask(...) function but if you check under the help, you will see it is not actually listed. This is often an indication that such a func should not be used freely by modellers)
PS: Good testing, well done :)
